# Countdown not working (Using Stopwatch Class + Dispatchertimer)

Tags: .net, vb.net, stopwatch, countdowntimer, dispatchertimer

I am initiating the Hours, Minutes and Seconds

And then Converting it to total milliseconds.

And then what i am doing is subtracting the Total MilliSeconds from Elapsed MilliSeconds

i.e `elms = cms - e.Milliseconds`

(Evaluated Milliseconds = calculated Millisec. - Stopwatch.elapsedMilliseconds)

and then converting the Evaluated Milliseconds back to the HH:MM:SS:MS format.

but its not working due to some logical error, Thats why i need some assistance. please help me a little
Here's My Code:

```
        Dim dd As Integer = 0
        Dim mm As Integer = 0
        Dim hh As Integer = 0
        Dim ss As Integer = 0
        Dim ms As Integer = 0
        Dim cms As Long = 0
        Dim elms As Long = 0

    Dim stopwatch As System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch = New System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch
    Dim dt As DispatcherTimer = New DispatcherTimer

    Private Sub StartButton_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles StartButton.Click

                hh = Hours.Text * 60 * 60 * 1000
                mm = Minutes.Text * 60 * 1000
                ss = Seconds.Text * 1000
                cms = hh + mm + ss
                hh = mm = ss = 0
                Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Start()

                dt.Interval = New TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 10)
                AddHandler dt.Tick, AddressOf ontimertick
                stopwatch.Start()
                dt.Start()

            End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub ontimertick()


            Dim e As New TimeSpan
            e = stopwatch.Elapsed

                elms = cms - e.Milliseconds
                ss = ((elms Mod (1000 * 60 * 60)) Mod (1000 * 60)) \ 1000
                mm = (elms Mod (1000 * 60 * 60)) \ (1000 * 60)
                hh = elms \ (1000 * 60 * 60)
                elms = elms Mod 1000

                MicroSeconds.Text = elms.ToString("00")
                Seconds.Text = ss.ToString("00")
                Minutes.Text = mm.ToString("00")
                Hours.Text = hh.ToString("00")
    End Sub
```

Comment: @DanielHilgarth I am unable to Trigger the Countdown timer and the methods specified below are not working as well

Answer (score 0):

The error is here :

```
ss = ((elms Mod (1000 * 60 * 60)) Mod (1000 * 60)) \ 1000
mm = (elms Mod (1000 * 60 * 60)) \ (1000 * 60)
hh = elms \ (1000 * 60 * 60)
elms = elms Mod 1000
```

it must be:

```
ss = ((elms Mod (1000 * 60 * 60)) Mod (1000 * 60)) \ 1000
 elms=elms-(ss*1000)
mm = (elms Mod (1000 * 60 * 60)) \ (1000 * 60)
 elms=elms-(mm*1000)
hh = elms \ (1000 * 60 * 60)
 elms=elms-(hh*1000)
elms = elms Mod 1000
```

OK?

Comment: No Not Okay, When i Execute it  and initiate with any time and call Start() it just turns to be 00:00:00.00

Answer (score 0):

You're over complicating it.  All you need to do is store the total time as a `TimeSpan` object.  Then, you can subtract the `StopWatch.Elapsed` time from it because it is also a `TimeSpan`.  Then, the `TimeSpan` object that results from the calculation will contain the remaining time.  For instance:

```
' Get the total desired time for count down
Dim total As New TimeSpan(Integer.Parse(Hours.Text), Integer.Parse(Minutes.Text), Integer.Parse(Seconds.Text))

' Later, get the time left and display on screen
Dim timeLeft As TimeSpan = total - stopwatch.Elapsed
Hours.Text = timeLeft.TotalHours
Minutes.Text = timeLeft.TotalMinutes
Seconds.Text = timeLeft.TotalSeconds
```

Obviously, just calling `Integer.Parse` like that isn't safe because the text boxes may contain non-numeric values.  You will need to add code to handle that.  For instance, if you want to just default to zero if an invalid entry is made, you could do something like this:

```
Dim totalHours As Integer
Dim totalMinutes As Integer
Dim TotalSeconds As Integer
Integer.TryParse(Hours.Text, totalHours)
Integer.TryParse(Minutes.Text, totalMinutes)
Integer.TryParse(Seconds.Text, totalSeconds)
Dim total As New TimeSpan(totalHours, totalMinutes, totalSeconds)
```

Or, if you want to display a validation error message, you could do something like this:

```
Dim total As TimeSpan
Try
    total = New TimeSpan(Integer.Parse(Hours.Text), Integer.Parse(Minutes.Text), Integer.Parse(Seconds.Text))
Catch ex As FormatException
    MessageBox.Show("Entries must be numeric.")
End Try
```

Comment: Thanks a Lot! Actually i am creating the Countdown for the very 1st time :) So just messed up with logics. Thanks for clearing my doubts

Comment: I am Getting a runtime error here:

'Dim total As New TimeSpan(Integer.Parse(Hours.Text), Integer.Parse(Minutes.Text), Integer.Parse(Seconds.Text))'

Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: You will have add code to handle invalid inputs.  You could do so either by putting a try/catch block around that line or by using `Integer.TryParse` instead of `Integer.Parse`.

Comment: Ahan not working 

Error: Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'TryParse' accepts this number of arguments.

Comment: Still not working :/

`Dim total As New TimeSpan(Integer.Parse(Hours.Text), Integer.Parse(Minutes.Text), Integer.Parse(Seconds.Text))`  
Error: Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: Are you sure you definitely have that try/catch block around it?  Did you try running the application outside of the debugger?  Depending on your debugger settings, it may break on even handled exception.

Comment: Yeap i just added  

`Dim totalHours As Integer
Dim totalMinutes As Integer
Dim TotalSeconds As Integer
Integer.TryParse(Hours.Text, totalHours)
Integer.TryParse(Minutes.Text, totalMinutes)
Integer.TryParse(Seconds.Text, totalSeconds)
Dim total As New TimeSpan(totalHours, totalMinutes, totalSeconds)`  
 before calling `start()'